# field does not have a default value error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a User Model with these fillable

```
protected $fillable = [
        'first name',
        'last name',
        'phoneNumber',
        'email',
        'password',
        'image',
        'reg_token'
    ];
```

I Have this migration and factory

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration {
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('firstname');
            $table->string('lastname');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('profile_picture');
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('phoneNumber');
            $table->string('reg_token');
            $table->string('person_type')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('person_id')->nullable();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
};
```

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

/**
 * @extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory<\App\Models\User>
 */
class UserFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function definition(): array
    {
        return [
            'firstname' => fake()->name(),
            'lastname' => fake()->name(),
            'email' => fake()->unique()->safeEmail(),
            'profile_picture' => fake()->imageUrl(),
            'email_verified_at' => now(),
            'password' => '$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi',
            'phoneNumber' => "0123456789",
            'reg_token' => Str::random(10),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Indicate that the model's email address should be unverified.
     */
    public function unverified(): static
    {
        return $this->state(fn(array $attributes) => [
            'email_verified_at' => null,
        ]);
    }
}
```

When I run `php artisan migrate:refresh --seed` I encounter this error saying that the field firstname does not have a default value

My understanding is that this error occurs because mySql does not allow inserting or updating an empty field when it does not have a default value

But in my code I'm not trying to insert an empty firstname anywhere

this is the error message

`` SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'firstname' doesn't have a default value (Connection: mysql, SQL: insert into `users` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2023-07-06 14:12:05, 2023-07-06 14:12:05)) ``

Comment: There are white spaces in 'first name' and 'last name' in $fillable but not in migration. you should fix this.

Answer (score 3):

in `$fillable`  array, you should set column names exactly as they are in db:

```
protected $fillable = [
        'firstname',
        'lastname',
        'phoneNumber',
        'email',
        'password',
        'image',
        'reg_token'
    ];
```

Comment: I corrected this and dropped the database and started all over again, I checked if everything is consistent, but still I get the same error

Comment: well, since you can recrate db, I recommend to change them to :
first_name, last_name ,phone_number as well Laravel convention

Comment: Also check all of your seeders if there is nay witch create users